# Show formatted text

Tags: php, html

I have a cms in which admins of my page log in and post various news.

The page is in Greek so I use utf-8 encoding.

They write their news/message/whatever in a textarea, and when they hit post, the following php script prepares the text so it can be stored in a mysql database.

```
$text = $_POST['text'];
$text = htmlentities($text, $quote_style = null, $charset = "UTF-8", $double_encode = null);
$text = mysql_real_escape_string( $text );
```

Then, when users go to the page, I fetch the text from the database and I include a view file whick looks something like this:

```
<p><?php echo $text; ?></p>
```

But when the text is displayed, it looks like a block of text, no line changes.

What can I do to show the text exactly as entered by the post's writer?

The reason I use htmlentities is that I don't really want the people who post news on the site to have the ability to post actual html code. In case it is not a good idea, please let me know.

I also tried using:

```
$text = $row['text'];
$text = html_entity_decode($text, $quote_style = null, $charset = "UTF-8");
```

before calling the view to display the text, but no luck there as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Output the text like this:

```
  <div><?php echo nl2br($text); ?></div>
```

[nl2br - Inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Answer (score 1):

You need [`nl2br()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) to insert  HTML `<br />` linebreaks:

```
<p><?php echo nl2br($text); ?></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

When a user enters something into a form, line breaks appear as line breaks in the form, because it's formatted as plain text.

When the browser parses the text, it doesn't care about text linebreaks, all it cares about is HTML linebreaks. Therefore, you need to convert your regular text linebreaks to HTML linebreaks.

This can be done using [`nl2br`](http://php.net/nl2br):

```
<p><?php echo nl2br($text); ?></p>
```

Comment: so the line breaks are actually stored, but the browser does not recognize them, and using the function above will do just that?

Comment: Yes. You can confirm this by viewing the source code of your generated page. In there, you will see that the linebreaks still exist.

Answer (score 1):

Use the *nl2br* function as [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php).

```
<p><?php echo nl2br($text); ?></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding nl2br call.

```
$text = $_POST['text'];
$text = htmlentities($text, null, "UTF-8", null);
$text = nl2br($text);
$text = mysql_real_escape_string( $text );
```

you must do it after htmlentities because it can break you're actual text changing "<" and ">" to entites:

```
&lt; / &gt;
```

Comment: Bad idea to replace the linebreak before writing to database. If you want to edit that text, you need to replace the `<br>` before output it into the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = $_POST['text'];
$text = mysql_real_escape_string( $text );

...save into database

$text = htmlentities($text, $quote_style = null, $charset = "UTF-8", $double_encode = null);

... show in view
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this your actual code?

```
$text = htmlentities($text, $quote_style = null, $charset = "UTF-8", $double_encode = null);
```

There's no need to specify what parameter you're defining, and it's going to be beneficial to leave the options as default like so:

```
htmlentities($text, ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, 'UTF-8');
```

If you're wanting line breaks to work after being entered into a textarea, you need to also call **nl2br** to convert new lines to HTML line breaks. This must be done after your call to htmlentities like so:

```
$text = nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['text'], ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, 'UTF-8'));
$text = mysql_real_escape_string($text);
```

Comment: His call works because assignment operator returns the assigned value. Its not the right way for doing that, but sometime it can be useful but confusing. like: **call($a = 1234); if($a == 1234) { echo "i'm here"; }** this passes 1234 to "call" function and enters the "if" if I'm not wrong.

Comment: @WoLfulus Good point, thinking back in the days of broken PHP. But even so, leaving out the default flags isn't a good thing. Updated. EDIT: Yes you're not wrong, var_dump(($a = 'c')); yields (string)'c'.

Comment: My edtor (bluefish) has the functions pre-typed with all variables passed to them as NULL. I just had not changed the values. I will search the htmlentities documentation for the syntax you mention.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `<pre>` tag instead of `<p>` tag.

Comment: That will also alter the apperance by default in most browsers (which means he would have to reformat the text using css) and it might not be correct in terms of semantics, depending on the context.